# html form field encode issue on Java servlet application

Tags: java, spring-mvc, servlets, encoding, character-encoding

I've got a annoying issue with character encoding for a web app running on Java servlet container. Here is the thing I've submitted:

[image]

And here is thing I've got:

[image]

As clearly shown the character `–` (`&#8211;`) has been changed to `â` after server received the post.

The app is running inside tomcat and supported by SpringMVC

**Update 1**

Server side debug shows the `req.request.request.coyoteRequest.parameters`:

[image]

Interesting thing is even my `<form>` tag has specified `accept-charset="utf-8"`, the parameter encoding is still `ISO-8859-1`

**Update 2**

HTML page parts relevant to encoding in my page:

1.

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
...
</head>
```

2.

```
<form action="/test/1925" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
```

**Update 3**

The chrome developer console shows the UTF-8 is not specified in any request header:

[image]

Comment: Hm, works with the UTF-8 endash "–"

Comment: It works with "-" typed from the keyboard. but customer sometimes copy string from ms word, that's where those special things get originated

Comment: Either you figure out where you missed the UTF-8 encoding, or convert all charcodes above ascii range to `&#num;` (i.e. the HTML entity) before outputting.

Comment: I've updated the question with my page in regarding to UTF-8 encoding. converting all chars to &#num; doesn't look like should be the way to go. Curious how other guys is handling non-ascii submitting. it should be a very primitive thing...

Answer (score 0):

Okay after tried everything on the frontend to get parameter posted to be encoded with utf-8, I still can't make it happen. In the end I get it worked by adding a filter to `web.xml` of the web app:

```
  <filter>
    <filter-name>SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>encoding</param-name>
      <param-value>utf-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```